# Using ParamArray in a VB.NET Property

Tags: vb.net

Is it possible to do something like this (don't know how to form correct syntax):

```
Public Property MyProperty as ParamArray Date
   Get
      ...
   End Get
   Set(ParamArray p as Date)
      ...
   End Set
End Property
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess if it is not possible to make a property will just make 2 methods:

```
Private itsDateLst As New List(Of Date)

Public Sub SetDateList(ByVal ParamArray p As Date) ...
Public Function GetDateList() As IList(Of Date) ...
```

Answer (score 1):

No; that is not possible.

Instead, you should make a readonly `Collection(Of DateTime)` property.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not possible. You'll have to define the property as `Date()` and create the array explicitly in order to assign it, though you should consider using a more appropriate collection type or interface rather than a simple array.